# Error al instalar pip de python3 en Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip

cuando trato de instalar pip con el comando `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` me da el siguiente error:

> Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
> Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
> Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
> No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes.
> Esto puede significar que usted pidió una
> situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución inestable, que
> algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se han sacado de
> «Incoming». La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la
> situación:
>
> Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
> python3-setuptools : Depende: python3-pkg-resources (= 59.6.0-1.2)
> pero 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1 va a ser instalado E: No se pudieron
> corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar el error